# Cancelling asked question

Tags: support, questions

Is there a way to cancel/close/delete a question I asked? There has been situations where I found a solution for my question, which actually makes the question insignificant. Not because I found the answer, but as I'd thought the problem was something else, and there's no point in that question anymore. I can't even seem to negative vote my own question.. So, is there something I can do?

Comment: Maybe it would be better posting an answer to your question explaining the reasons why the question was "wrong" thus helping other people how have the same question.

Answer (score 2):

Each question has a `delete` link at the bottom. There next to the `edit`, `close` and some other links. Just click it. Sometimes a question isn't eligible for deleting, because it contains voted answers. You may want to try to flag for moderator attention then.